# Cyrillic not showing properly in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

When i insert Cyrillic in the database I've got something like this Ð£Ñ€Ð¾Ðº 2 - ÐŸÑŠÑ€Ð²Ð°Ñ‚Ð° Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ð³Ñ€Ð°Ð¼Ð°. How can I fix it? I'm using utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: What makes you think that's what's in the database? How are you fetching it, and how are you displaying it? (And how are you inserting it?)

Comment: Where do you use this encoding (db, php,db field)?

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty solution
issue an SQL query

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

every time you connect to your database.

Answer (score 0):

Try using sql function SET NAMES 'utf8'  right after connection.
Check what is the encoding of the field in the database.
Check MySQL connection collation